# Regex in Shopify filters

Tags: regex, shopify, liquid

I am trying to remove or replace **?page=2** from Shopify link with regex. Is regex not working here?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url | replace: '\?page=\d+','' }}" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before posting a question, please refer to How to Ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: It [doesn't seem Liquid supports regex with `replace`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/202), you will need to create a [custom filter](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shopify don't support regex and it will probably never support it because of security reasons. ( I'm quoting them on this )

In your case you can use the following approach in order to get only the URL:

```
{% assign canonical_url = canonical_url | split: '\?page=' %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url[0] }}" />
```

Comment: I have a new problem with tag url. How to do it with a such construction?
` {% if template contains 'collection' and current\_tags %} <meta name="robots" content="noindex" /> <link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}" /> {% else %} <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical\_url }}" /> {% endif %} `

Comment: I need a canonical link with a collection "red-carpet" only. <link rel="canonical" href="/collections/red-carpet" /> not a <link rel="canonical" href="/collections/red-carpet/extra-long" />

  {% if template contains 'collection' and current\_tags %} 
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}" /> 
  {% else %} {% assign canonical_url = canonical_url | split: '?page=' %}
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url[0] }}" /> 
  {% endif %}
The construction is not working